# Is it ok to send an email request to hiring manager for an interview for an internal position?

Tags: job-search

I request your help for making the best move to get an interview. Here is the case. I am working under the President of a top university and due to funding issues, my project will not be extended. He tried to keep me within the team but due to administrative issues, he can't keep me for long.

Meanwhile, I applied for another position within the university. It's a collaboration between my university and another institute close by and falls under the office of the President. However, the role reports to the Director of a school and the director reports to President. I talked about this position to the President last week and let him know my interest. He explained to me about the position, who all are involved in it, and who is the hiring person, etc. He also asked me to update my profile with his name as the reference.

**It's almost 4 weeks after I applied for the position and I haven't heard anything about it.  I called the HR and they said it's still open and my resume is with the hiring manager. Since the President asked me to keep him as the reference,and also provided the details of the hiring person I'm wondering whether it's a good move to contact the hiring person and request for an interview?**

Comment: Rather than call and ask for a interview you might be better to call and ask if there is any additional information on your qualifications or clarification you can provide.  Have you asked the President if he has heard any feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Your concerns appear to be two fold:

1. Issues of protocol
2. Causing a ripple that can backfire and disqualify you

You are right to be concerned about both in this scenario.  Normally, I think it is always a good idea to be proactive and not let roadblocks block your road.  However, in this scenario, you are dealing with an position that the President of the college cannot directly influence.  However, he/she has made it clear that they have some weight as a reference.  In addition, he openned the door for you to reach out to the correct parties and how those parties will determine the pool of interviewees.

However, what he/she did not do was put you in direct contact with such individual.  That's the part that seems curious to me.  Some people do not like to feel influenced, and they also have to avoid appearing partial in any way.  Who knows what else is going on in this hiring managers mind.

I'd seek an opportunity to socialize your name with the hiring individual, but do not be pushy.  You want your name to become slightly more familiar, with the potential to associate your face with that name AND the president of your university.

See if you can arrange an introduction via the President of your university, informal or formal.  Maybe some mutual event.  Observe the President's reaction to such an idea, since you seem to be on great terms with him/her.  You might get more information you need by being more direct with someone who has insight.

You can, of course, attempt to meet with the hiring manager to hear more about the position if they are available, but again...something seems off, and you don't want to put a negative impression out there just yet if the person is not familiar with you.  Be creative and search for ways to socialize with this individual.  Perhaps even sending a postcard from your university expressing your eagerness to interview for the position.

As you know, you are not dealing with a regular job hunt scenario.  You must approach it a bit more asymmetrical and mindful.  More than likely, the pool of rivals are doing the exact same thing as you are.  So you must be diligent and flexible.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

As an option, tell the President you have heard nothing back.  Obviously, the Pres wants to keep you around, and maybe will make a quick phone call or email ending your wait.

There could be some political, schedule, or funding issue of why you haven't heard back.  Maybe the hiring manager lost your resume.  Maybe they are too busy.

Also, consider a backup plan.  Get your resume together, and start looking elsewhere.  Maybe the President can be a good reference for you.